# Is it possible to force RefEdit control to select a single cell?

Tags: excel, vba

excel gurus!

I have a userform with a `RefEdit` control in which I need to select a range with a single cell. Is it possible to prevent `RefEdit` to extend selection to more than one cell?

Comment: No  - you'll need to ask the user to select only a single cell

Comment: Hello @TimWilliams! Your comment is welcome. Of course, I can set an "error trap" to force the one-cell selection, but I was wondering if it was possible to get RefEdit to do the job for me...

Comment: The answer is "no, you need to validate the user's input"

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the comments of the above guru's an attempt: 
(Changing the selected range to only the first cell)
(adjust RefEdit1 to your RefEdit name, and use KeyDown-event to make sure ranges are not typed in)

```
    Private Sub RefEdit1_Change()
    Dim x As Variant, apo As String
        On Error Resume Next 'just to make sure
            If InStr(1, RefEdit1.Text, "'") > 0 Then apo = "'"  'for sheetnames with spaces
            If InStr(1, RefEdit1.Text, "!") > 0 Then
            x = Split(RefEdit1.Value, "!")
                If InStr(x(0), ":") > 0 Then x(0) = apo & Application.Substitute(Split(x(0), ":")(0), "'", "") & apo
                    Sheets(Application.Substitute(Split(x(0), ":")(0), "'", "")).Activate
'splitting on : for selecting multiple sheets, Activate for first selected sheet
                    RefEdit1.Value = x(0) & "!" & Range(x(1)).Cells(1).Address(True, True)
                End If
    End Sub
```